# Simulator not getting location

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm following [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/02_RootViewController.html) to learn about Core Data. I'm currently on section 4, Adding Events. In section 2 the tutorial says that the Add Button will become active seconds after I am prompted by the Simulator to get my location, but it never becomes active, any idea what might be happening?

PS: If I hardcode the button to be active before getting location I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

On the following line:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

EDIT: Posting more code to get a bigger picture

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Locations";

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addEvent)];
    addButton.enabled = NO;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButton;

    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];

    eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}
```

This is the method where I get there error:

```
-(void)addEvent{
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];

    if(location){
        return;
    }

    Event *event = (Event *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    event.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.latitude];
    event.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.longitude];
    event.creationDate = [NSDate date];

    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

    }

    [eventsArray insertObject:event atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

}
```

And my appDidLaunch method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if(!context){

    }

    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO];

    [rootViewController release];

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `NSMutableArray` in the code you posted. The problem from the error is that you are trying to access an object (at index `0`) in an empty `NSMutableArray`. Find that array, and you will probably find the problem.

Comment: I updated my code with the other relevant methods in my viewDidLoad is where I allocate the NSMutableArray that is a property of my RootViewController

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a CLLocation object. In the third line of the addEvent method you have if(location) {
return
}
so basically every time you successfully get a location object from CLLocation *location = [locationManager location]; you just return without executing the rest of the method.